# Aliasing columns based on cross-reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with over 400 columns, and these are named with our vendor's archaic naming system. I need to move this data into a new table which uses our company's naming conventions, so I have to change the names of these 400 columns.

Fortunately, I also have a table that cross-references the current column names with what they should become, like so:

```
Acronym  | Name
----------------
A        | ColumnNameA
B        | ColumnNameB
C        | ColumnNameC
```

etc...

So my question is this: 
If it were only a few rows, I could easily do

```
SELECT 
   A AS ColumnNameA, 
   B AS ColumnNameB 
FROM 
   Table
```

But there are just too many columns to do this by hand. What's the best way to dynamically change column names in a SELECT statement based off of a cross-ref table?

My effort so far:

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM Table'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

but I have no idea how to set `@columns` to be a dynamically generated list of all the acronyms as the final column names. Is this even a viable approach?

Comment: Is the a one-off operation?  Or do you expect this to a repeatable action which must be dynamic as new columns are added?

Comment: And how are you validating that every column name in the acronym table is a valid column in the target table?

Comment: @MikeRyan That's unclear. We may be able to get away with doing it just once. The columns aren't going to change, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += ',' + QUOTENAME(Acronym) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM dbo.AcronymTable;

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, N'') + ' FROM dbo.Table;';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but this looks like it will produce an extra comma before the first column `SELECT , col1, col2.....`

Comment: @cadrell0 that's what the `STUFF` is for.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I have a co-worker that loves to use `STUFF` and it confuses me every time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add an `int` field that determines the order of columns so it matches from source to target.  Then you can:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO dbo.Target SELECT '

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + Acronym + ','
FROM ConversionTable
ORDER BY OrderColumn

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, (LEN(@SQL) - 1))    

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM SourceTable'
```